# show more fields on user/id on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm searching the way to show custom fields that I've added on the users in the default view for the user/11. It displays only the username and the History.

I can make a view for that but I want to use the original page (user/id).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look under `Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage fields`, and locate the panel `Fieldname field settings`.  There you should be able to make the field visible when someone view the user's profile by making the  field "Public".

Comment: OK thanks. Now if I want to show the avatard (picture of the user - fiels that is included natively, how can I do? )

Thanks !

Comment: 1. Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings.
2. Locate the panel Personalization settings, select Enable user pictures.

Next, ensure your user pictures display in your theme. These are enabled by default in Bartik, so you may have to check this with any new theme you add.

1. Go to Appearance and click "Settings" for the theme you have enabled as default.
2. In the Toggle display settings, select User pictures in posts and/or User pictures in comments.